# Automatically open URL after my media player avi file finishes

Tags: html, avi

**I want to automatically open URL on the same page after my media player avi file finish 
and here is my code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
  <title>WELCOME TO LOTUS TENDA WEBSITE</title>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#000000">
<br><br>
<table border="0" align=center>
   <tr>
     <td> 
     <object id="MediaPlayer1" CLASSID="CLSID:22d6f312-b0f6-11d0-94ab-0080c74c7e95" codebase="http://activex.microsoft.com/activex/controls/mplayer/en/nsmp2inf.cab#Version=5,1,52,701"

standby="Loading Microsoft Windows® Media Player components..." type="application/x-oleobject" width="890" height="500">
<param name="fileName" value="intro.avi">
<param name="animationatStart" value="true">
<param name="transparentatStart" value="true">
<param name="autoStart" value="true">
<param name="showControls" value="false">
<param name="Volume" value="-450">
<embed type="application/x-mplayer2" 
pluginspage="http://www.microsoft.com/Windows/MediaPlayer/" src="intro.avi" 
name="MediaPlayer1" width=890 height=500 autostart=1 showcontrols=0 volume=-450>
</object>
     </td>
       </tr>
 </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you show the complete code, please ?

Comment: i already sent my code ...plz help

Comment: it's urgent... the code already shown

Comment: I don't know if they are any callback (event) functions for `<object>`, but if you use the new HTML5 `<video>`, there's `onended`! ->[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/MYERh/). BTW welcome on Stack Overflow!!

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with JavaScript by sampling the `PlayState` property of the object. From quick test that I conducted, it will be 2 before the video started playing, 3 while it's playing and 0 when the video finished playing.

Add this inside your `<head>` section:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {
    var oVid = document.getElementById("MediaPlayer1");
    window.setTimeout(function CheckVidState() {
        if (oVid.PlayState == 0) {
            document.location = "OtherPage.html";
            return true;
        }
        window.setTimeout(CheckVidState, 10);
        return false;
    }, 10);
};
</script>
```

This will redirect the user to `OtherPage.html` when the video finished playing.

Comment: Why don't you use `window.setInterval(function(){}, 10)`?

Comment: @ComFreek because it's harder to cancel that timer - instead I just "call myself" again if needed.

Comment: im new in coding could u plz send me fuul code and i'll edit it

Comment: This is the full code, if you need someone to do everything for you I fear your only option is to hire a programmer. Good luck to you.

Comment: thank you shadow wizard the code worked for me but what if i want to stand still for 2 seconds after video finish then redirect

Comment: In such case change the line `document.location = "OtherPage.html";` to be this instead: `window.setTimeout(function() { document.location = "OtherPage.html"; }, 2000);` and it will wait for two seconds before redirecting.

Comment: Cheers, glad you were able to use the code properly.. you can mark the answer as the correct by clicking the empty V icon to the left.

Answer (score 0):

```
setInterval(function () {
                if ($("MediaPlayer1")[0].playState == 1) {
                    $("MediaPlayer1")[0].URL = "nextVideo.wmv";
                }
            }, 100);
```